# Display confirmation messagebox c# in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

i found these codes while researching but they're not what i really want:

**1st solution:**

```
private void MsgBoxConfirmDelete(string sMessage)
{
    string msg = "<script language=\"javascript\">";
    msg += "var conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this image?');";
    msg += "  if(conf == true){ (alert(....));}";
    msg += "</script>";
    Response.Write(msg);
}
```

**2nd solution:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript; 
    if (!ReturnValue()) 
    { 
        string strconfirm = "<script>if(!window.confirm('Are you sure?')){window.location.href='Default.aspx'}</script>"; 
        CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false); 
    } 
} 
bool ReturnValue() 
{ 
    return false; 
}
```

Most of the solutions i've found is "onclientclick/onclick", however what i need is to display a confirmation message while running my method which is kinda "IN BETWEEN". Thus, i needed a IF/ELSE so badly. Anyone knows how to retrieve the result from a confirmation message like these?

For example:

> Message: Found some duplicates data while reading, are you sure you
>   want to continue? Prompt:  YES/NO

Answer (score 1):

Do some research on asynchronous request handling. The client web code will need to make calls back to the server to retrieve an updated 'status' on your data processing process. The server code can send back a general status (i.e. completed 15 out of 200 records) or it can send back a signal to prompt the use for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ModalPopupExtender(ajax control) .
On button Click show popup.
In Control give targetControlID to your container having the message you wants to display and two respective buttons for confirmation.

Answer (score -1):

I found this tutorial on the web and it seems to be behaving correctly:

```
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this list and it's related jobs? There is no going back!","Confirm delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
               // a 'DialogResult.Yes' value was returned from the MessageBox
               // proceed with your deletion
            }
```

Comment: It's for winform application :(